# Click Event Working in jQuery 1.9.1 but not 1.10.2

Tags: jquery, onclick

This `.on` click event works [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sinclair_lewis/NCTr3/) with jQuery 1.9.1 but not 1.10.1. (You can change the jQuery version on the upper left of the jsfiddle.) The current version of WordPress (3.7.1) has jQuery 1.10.2 -- I'd greatly prefer not to use an older jQuery version.

```
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" name="TEXT_15-1-0-1" id="TEXT_15-1-0-1">
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" name="TEXT_16-1-0-1" id="TEXT_16-1-0-1">
<br />
<p>Click to copy values from the first two fields  
<input type="checkbox" name="CopyfromContactInformation-1_1" id="CopyfromContactInformation-1_1">
<br />
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" name="fname-1-0-1" id="fname-1-0-1">
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" name="lname-1-0-1" id="lname-1-0-1">

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(document).on('click', '#CopyfromContactInformation-1_1' ,function(e){
        $('#fname-1-0-1').val($('#TEXT_15-1-0-1').val());
        $('#lname-1-0-1').val($('#TEXT_16-1-0-1').val());
    });
});
```

I've tried using `$("#CopyfromContactInformation-1_1").on("click",".selector",function(){`. I've also looked into jQuery's migrate plugin, but WordPress already includes that.

Thanks

Comment: It does work in 1.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the `noConflict()` mode to prevent compatibility problems with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress can link.

The global `$` shortcut for jQuery is not available in this mode, so you need to use the following wrapper:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Comment: If you might want to use the standard version jQuery, follow this guide http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-load-jquery-from-google-cdn